# Regular Regex is not working as expected in Bitbucket client side hooks

Tags: regex, git, bitbucket, regex-group, atlassian-sourcetree

I was trying to enforce a regex match to keep a consistent naming convention when creating a branch in bitbucket.

My regex requirements:

> 1. starts with `feature/` or `release/`
> 2. must be followed by `ABCD-`
> 3. have any number after that (at least one digit is mandatory)
> 4. must end with only numbers, no other character is allowed

what I am trying are these alternatives:

1. `^(feature|release)\/(ABCD-\d+$).*`
2. `^(feature|release)\/(ABCD-\d+$)`

It should be working fine, I checked on [regex101](https://regex101.com/)
and my example `feature/ABCD-99` is matching in this site.

But when I am using the same regex in a `.git/hooks/pre-push`, my source tree is failing even when I supply the tested example. i.e. `feature/ABCD-99` is failing.

Please help me understand, do Regex behave differently at different sites/vendors?

How can i correct my regex to get it worked for Atlassian Bitbucket (I am using SourceTree).

Adding my pre-push script here:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "inside pre-push hook"
local_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

echo "local branch is: $local_branch "

branch_regex="^(feature|release)\/(ABCD-\d+$).*"

if [[ ! $local_branch =~ $branch_regex ]]
then
     echo "Bad naming convention of branch. Rejected"
     exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Adding output when giving ABCD-99 (valid scenario regex) in source tree:

Pushing to git

inside pre-push hook

local branch is: feature/ABCD-99

Bad naming convention of branch. Rejected

Comment: Can you show us your `pre-push` script?  There are a couple of different types of regex and the tools you're using might require a particular kind.

Comment: @bk2204 added in question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing is because you're using bash and the `=~` match requires a POSIX extended regular expression.  That means that you can use character classes like `[0-9]`, but you cannot use Perl-compatible notation like `\d`.  In general, Perl-compatible regexes are very powerful, but they require an additional library whereas POSIX extended regexes are available on almost every Unix system, so they're a better fit for a portable shell like bash.

So your regex should be something like this: `^(feature|release)\/ABCD-[0-9]+$`.

Do note that the `[[` command and the `=~` operator to it are bash extensions and are not found in other shells.  Using them is fine, but if you want to use bash, your shebang needs to be `#!/bin/bash` (or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), since `/bin/sh` is not bash on all systems (e.g., Debian, Ubuntu, the BSDs, and some macOS systems).  The POSIX way to write this check is this:

```
if ! echo "$local_branch" | grep -qsE "$branch_regex"
then
     echo "Bad naming convention of branch. Rejected"
     exit 1
fi
```

On Linux systems, the `regex(7)` manual page describes the syntax allowed for POSIX extended (modern) and basic (obsolete) regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of brain storming and trail and error methods, found out some how atlassian/bitbucket Git/ Sourcetree is not ready to take '\d' to match digits for a Regex, instead they are allowing only '[0-9]'

Changed above code from
`^(feature|release)\/(ABCD-\d+$)` to `^(feature|release)\/(ABCD-[0-9]+$)` to make it work.